# how to get git repo working on server

Tags: git

I have been working on my project on my local machine and am now ready to put it online.  What I thought was the way to do that:

1. Create a git repo `git init`
2. Add and Commit the project files
3. Create a git repo on server via ssh `git --bare init`
4. Push the repo to the server
5. The project is online and navigating to the correct URL will load the project (ie www.example.com)

I have done steps 1-4 and step 5 is not so much the case.  Could anyone tell me where I have gone wrong?

Also, I can see the git repo via ftp but it looks the same as before the push, is that normal or is that the problem?  I also can't see any of the files, which I didn't think was right.  I would assume it simply didn't push right but it says it did and I was able to pull from it fine.

Comment: I went ahead and made that an answer, so that it might be accepted, and others will know your question has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do sounds like deploying using a git commit hook. But unless you know the terms it can be tricky to find the info you need.

Basically a "commit hook" is a script that gets run on the server when you push to the git repository. You can do many things with that script, but putting a copy of the current master branch into some deploy location is pretty common - and what you're looking for.

There's a pretty good example of how to set it all up on this page: http://www.sitepoint.com/one-click-app-deployment-server-side-git-hooks/

Answer (score 2):

`--bare` repositories don't have a working copy; they only have the contents of the `.git` directory. Which, unless you really dig into it, will always look roughly the same.